# How to get value returned by promise outside the scope using Vue and Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I find it difficult to use the value returned by the firestore promise in other methods as I am getting undefined. I tried to use async/await in the manner below and still didn't work out.

```
get_board_details(){         db.collection('members').where('board_id','==',this.$route.params.groupslug).get().then(querySnapshot=>{
                     querySnapshot.forEach( async doc=>{
                       this.owner_id  = await doc.data().owner_id;
                      })
                    })
                  console.log(this.owner_id)
                  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following, make sure your this.$route.params.groupslug is correct beforehand.

```
get_board_details(){      
 db.collection('members').where('board_id','==',this.$route.params.groupslug).get().then(querySnapshot=>{
                     querySnapshot.forEach( doc=>{
                       this.owner_id  = doc.data().owner_id;
                       console.log(this.owner_id)
                      })
                    })
                  },
```

Comment: thank you, I got the expected result when I tried this but I got undefined if I try to use this.owner_id in another method

Comment: you will need to check for null/undefined before using the owner_id in another method. The reason being that your db call is an async function. And the reason why my code works is because the console.log is within the .then().